# Angular2 Observable fromEvent keyup map Property 'key' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Please, how can I fix this code ?

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup')
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(ev => ev.key)
    .scan((acc, one) => acc + one)
    .subscribe(term => console.log(term));
```

I get the error Property 'key' does not exist on type '{}'

UPDATE

As in the comment of @jb-nizet ( thx so much :) )
I worked it out with

```
Observable.fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
map(ev => ev['key'])
```

Or tell TypeScript that your initial Observable is an `Observable<KeyboardEvent>`

```
const obs: Observable<KeyboardEvent> = Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup');
obs.debounceTime()...
```